# Testing routes with MVC4 and MvcContrib.TestHelper

Tags: .net, testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to test the routes of my MVC4 site with MvcContrib.TestHelper. When I do something like that:

```
"~/".ShouldMapTo<myController>(x => x.Index());
```

I have an error like "System.Security.VerificationException: Method MvcContrib.TestHelper.RouteTestingExtensions.ShouldMapTo: type argument
'myController' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TController'.

I did a quick search and I found that article: http://www.kevinlabranche.com/blog/UsingMVCContrib3TestHelpersWithASPNetMVC4Beta.aspx but it doesn't work. In fact, I suppose it works with MVC4 Beta but not with MVC4.

I know there are other solutions for testing my rules, I just love the way and cleanness of that one. Any solution to make it work would be very appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kevin labranche suggested in [his blog](http://www.kevinlabranche.com/blog/UsingMVCContrib3TestHelpersWithASPNetMVC4Beta.aspx) , I downloaded the source code, compiled with visual studio 2012.

Comment: I used the binding redirect that Kevin suggested in his blog and it worked fine in Visual Studio 2010 with MVC4 (not beta).  I did have to add some lines to the app.config so the xml/config file would be in the correct format.